# Using not in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add opacity to a div which contains anchor tag,image, caption(span) .

On hovering of caption i want to show my caption only making all of div blur...
So  i had used not like this

```
$(this).not('.Caption').css('opacity', '0.4');
```

my body is like

```
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src=""/></a>
    <span class='Caption'>caption</span>     
</div>
```

See my fiddle for better understanding..[FiDDle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggLG8/2/)

**UPDATE:** Actually i am trying to implement like the last demo in [Plugin](http://captionjs.com/) , lastly i ended like the fiddle above

Comment: `$(this).find(':not(.Caption)').css('opacity', '0.4');`

Comment: @Satpal - you're sure that was a valid edit? Perhaps the OP doesn't really have a class attribute for that span element...

Comment: @Lix, Yes that was valid edit, OP has provided fiddle. Its mentioned there.

Comment: @Satpal - ahh.. I didn't look at the fiddle... Carry on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean like this? => http://jsfiddle.net/ggLG8/6/

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
      $(this).children().not('.Caption').css('opacity', '0.4');
},function(){
    $(this).children().not('.Caption').css('opacity', '1');
});
```

also you have to remove the `opacity:0.4;` from the `.thumbnail:hover` in CSS

Comment: This doesn't do anything.

Comment: @TimBJames check out the fiddle, the `.Caption` opacity is not changing, but the rest are!

Comment: @user3860465 okay, I did, but I don't see a "caption"

Comment: @user3860465 oh I got it, you mean you wanna make it look like this => http://jsfiddle.net/ggLG8/9/

Comment: thanx..i really appreciate u..still i am confusing in jquery..certain options for only certain situations..:)

Comment: you'll adapt as time goes on, don't worry, glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(this).find('*').not('.Caption').css('opacity', '0.4');
```

This would set the opacity to all the child elements except one with class `Caption`.

Answer (score 0):

this happend because ".caption" element is inside of your "Div"
try this:

```
<div class="someclass">
<div class="thumbnail" >
<a class="fancybox" href="http://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" rel="group1">
    <img width="150" height="120" src="http://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg"/>
</a>
    </div>
    <span class='Caption' contenteditable='true'>Caption</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't your jQuery, but because you are applying opacity to an element that contains other elements. When you do this, all the elements within the containing element inherit the opacity.

The simplest solution would be to remove the opacity and just change the background color of the `.thumbnail` element, and remove the opacity from the css style.

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
      $(this).not('.Caption').css('background-color', 'rgba(249, 160, 160, 0.4)');
      $(this).find('.Caption').animate({
          opacity: 'show',
          bottom: 0
      }, 'fast');    
});
```

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggLG8/7/)